# Attention block: can't prolong the vertical line to the bottom of the text

Tags: css

This is meant to be an attention block.

Could you help me:

1. Make the black line stretch to the bottom of the text.
2. The symbol of radiation looks ok here. But in my real project its top is higher than the top of vertical black line. I even don't know why. The code is copied exactly.

Could you give me a kick?

```css
.attention-block::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f7ba";
 font-size: 56px;
 float: left;
 color: red;
 border-right: 10px solid black; 
 padding-right: 30px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 display: block;
}

.attention-block {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #FEDB39, white);
 padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="attention-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset she</p>
```

Comment: For the symbol above line, you probably have some css in your project which could have changed the vertical alignment somehow, you will have to inspect and find out. You would need to reproduce the issue here for us to really help you with that one

Comment: I can't make before element bigger. It is for attention blocks: everything should be unified all over the project. And the text always differs. I seem to need the before element and the text be displayed as blocks. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh you mean the line extends to the bottom of all of the text, sorry I misunderstood that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the pseudo-class `position: absolute` and adjust paddings.

This works because I'm specifying a `top` AND `bottom` position. This means the element will stretch to fill that inner space. Just remember that absolute position doesn't respect padding so I had to make the `top, left, bottom` numbers match the padding about the paragraph.

Also, **don't forget to give the container a position** (`relative` in this case) so that the absolute positioned element has a context.

```css
.attention-block::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f7ba";
 font-size: 56px;
 color: red;
 border-right: 10px solid black; 
 padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    /* top right bottom left */
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;

}

.attention-block {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #FEDB39, white);
 padding: 40px 40px 40px 160px;
    /* top right bottom left */
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="attention-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset she</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `float` for the icon, and just make the parent `display:flex`.

```css
.attention-block::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f7ba";
  font-size: 56px;
  /* float: left; */
  color: red;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.attention-block {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FEDB39, white);
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex; /* added this */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="attention-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. is simply
  dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
  five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset she</p>
```